# Keil debugger speed, logging variables

Tags: debugging, logging, stm32, keil

I can succesfully use Watch1 and Watch2 to check if variables values are changing.

What i'm missing is the possibility to log each values at really high speed.
I've tried with a simple user defined function

```
FUNC void aval(void) {
    int i;
    exec("log > MyValues.log");
    for(i=0;i<9600;i++){
        printf("a= %d\n", l->a);
    }
    exec("log off");
}
```

But of course it is terrible in both speed and GUI responsiveness.
Even if "l" is a volatile pointer declared globally and "a" is a volatile field of "l" struct i'm not able to use the Analyzer to log it (actually i can't see anything in real time using the analyzer with a STLINK).

Since eventually i've to post-processing the data to see if everything is fine i need to log the "l->a" value with the highest frequency i can.
How can i achieve this?

I'm on a STM32F4 @ 84Mhz

Regards,

Comment: It will be far from the "real time". You need to use more decent Jtag deug probes and trace and debug macrocells

Comment: Can i reach a speed of 10 khz for example? If so how can i do that?

Comment: It will affect the program execution or peripheral usage. Read about SWO as for this speed probably you will have to write your own routines.